# Can a Tri-State buffer be used with AC signals?

Tags: audio, tri-state

I'm trying to switch an analog audio line from its given channel to analog ground when a specific line goes low (in this case, the DACs charge pump goes low when it shuts down).

Would a tri-state buffer degrade or in anyway impact the AC signal going from the A side to the Y side?

Comment: However you detect loss of charge pump signal, you can use an NFET open drain as a  switch to 0V

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - The charge pump simply shuts off on its own, but that's a great idea! I can tie the AGND to the output lines when the CP is low via the NFET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any digital logic part will seriously distort an analog audio signal.

A digital gate will only output either a logic High or a logic Low, with nothing in between, while an analog signal must smoothly vary between its positive and negative peaks.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are specialised "analogue switch" ICs for this.